# Unable to launch Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda Navigator MacOS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter

I have a problem with launching jupyter notebook on the Anaconda Navigator, which is on my Mac. This is the error message that shows when I try to launch it. What should I do?

```
  Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
  PYTHONPATH = '/Applications/NEURON-7.4/nrn/lib/python'
  program name = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
  sys.executable = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
  sys.path = [
    '/Applications/NEURON-7.4/nrn/lib/python',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python38.zip',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python3.8',
    '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000001083335c0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: have you tried typing `jupyter notebook` directly into terminal?

Comment: Yes I have. It gives me this: jupyter: command not found

Comment: That means `jupyter` is not installed so you can do `pip3 install jupyter` in your conda environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! However, I am still running into the same error as above when I run the pip3 install jupyter command in terminal. What might be the issue?

Comment: type `jupyter notebook` into terminal now that you have it installed. From my experience, I've found that the Anaconda Navigator is finicky on MacOS so I just launch everything from the terminal

Comment: It still says that jupyter: command not found, so I am assuming I have not installed it yet. Is there another way to install jupyter utilizing terminal? I already installed python 3.8 and the anaconda navigator. Within anaconda, jupyterlab and spyder all function, but jupyter notebook will not work.

Comment: From the information above, it is using python 2.7 as the default, make sure you set your conda environment to be using python 3 also what is the output when you type `which python3`

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 is what it shows when I type which python3. How would I set my conda environment to be using python 3 through terminal?